# Is it possible to send emails in python?

Tags: python, email

My goal is to send emails entirely from python. I want to do it all from scratch, maybe go as far as building an email server in python if someone hasn't done it already. I want to do this because I'm basically tired of using Postfix or the common email providers with the standard SMTP/POP/IMAP libraries. Also, another reason I want to try to do this is because I want to try and understand better how the email protocols work.

I'm not entirely sure where to start. Maybe I should take a look at the Postfix source code and try and make a python SMTP server. I know it would be much easier to just stick with the standard way of doing it instead of building from scratch, but like I said, this is more of an educational study for me to learn how it all works, I will very likely never use it in production.

So, give me ideas guys. Where should I start? If you know of an article that may enlighten me, please post it. --Thanks

Comment: This isn't really on topic for Stack Overflow, I recommend you take a look at the documentation on the [email package](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email.html).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's been done before, but you can always make one if you want.

[smtpd](http://pymotw.com/2/smtpd/) was a Python Module of the Week.

[This](http://blog.codinghorror.com/so-youd-like-to-send-some-email-through-code/) is some good reading that was provided in a similar SO question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690965/a-simple-smtp-server).

I've used [this](https://docs.python.org/2/library/email-examples.html) before when I was working on a project.

Comment: Reading through the links now. I hadn't known about SMTPD.