# How to create a free SMTP server

Tags: python, email, smtp

I am not at all familiar with `SMTP` but I am working on sending `emails` through `Python` code. I have the code but I need to pass `SMTP` `host name` for it to actually work. Is there any service which provides a free `SMTP` service that I leverage for testing out my code? I looked around to create my own `SMTP server` but couldn't find something that provides a step by step guide to create a `SMTP server`. I want to create a free server(or if there is any free service) that will provide me with a host name(`ip` address) so that I can put that host name in my python code and execute it from any machine.

If anyone can point me in the right direction it will be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

```
import smtplib

username = 'user'
password = 'pwd'

from_addr = 'username@gmail.com'
to_addrs = 'username@gmail.com'

msg = "\r\n".join([
  "From: username@gmail.com",
  "To: username@gmail.com",
  "Subject: subject",
  "",
  "message"
  ])

server = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com:587')
server.ehlo()
server.starttls()
server.login(username, password)
server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addrs, msg)
server.quit()
```

You can use `mutt` linux command also [here](http://www.mutt.org/doc/mutt.1.txt).

See :
https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html
https://support.google.com/a/answer/176600?hl=en

Comment: is `smtp.gmail.com:587` a valid SMTP host name that I can actually use in my code or is just a sample example?

Comment: @user2916886 check the last link. It is mentioned there. I think you need a gmail account or similar. It's best you read it yourself.

Comment: I am getting `OSError: [WinError 10013] An attempt was made to access a socket in a way forbidden by its access permissions` when I am trying to run my code using `'smtp.gmail.com:587`

Comment: I was able to resolve above error by disabling email sending blocking in my antivirus as well as enabling `access from less secure app` in my gmail account

Comment: the answer although a working one, does not respond whatsoever to the asked question which is "how to create a free SMTP server". the asnwer responds more to the question "how to use an existing GMAIL account as SMTP server to send mails using python". i think you answer can be found in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690965/a-simple-smtp-server-in-python

Answer (score 2):

You need service like https://mailtrap.io/. You'll get SMTP server address (eventually port number) that you point your application to. All e-mails produced by your application will be then intercepted by mailtrap (thus not delivered to the real `To:` address).

They offer free variant that seems to be suitable for your needs.